# How do I save two objects at once in a Rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, foreign-keys, relation

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  How do I save two objects with one form?  I have these two models …

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :my_object_times
  attr_accessor :hour, :minute, :second

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :my_object_times
end
```

and

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_object
end
```

I want to submit a single form that creates both a MyObject and a MyObjectTime object.  So I created my form

```
<%= form_for @my_object do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Time" %>
    <%= select_tag('my_object[hour]', options_for_select((0..12).to_a), {:prompt => 'Select Hour'} ) %> hrs
    <%= select_tag('my_object[minute]', options_for_select((0..60).to_a), {:prompt => 'Select Minutes'} ) %> min
    <%= select_tag('my_object[second]', options_for_select((0..60).to_a), {:prompt => 'Select Seconds’} ) %> sec
    <%= f.fields_for :my_object_time do |mot| %>
      <%= mot.number_field :time_in_ms %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= button_to "Save", { :action => "create" }, :method => :post, :class => 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and here’s my controller …

```
  def create
    @my_object = MyObject.new(my_object_params)
    @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    @my_object.user = @current_user
    if @my_object.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to controller: "users", action: "index", notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
      end
    else
      format.html { render action: "index" }
    end
  end

  private

    def my_object_params
      # Main Code goes here
      params[:my_object][:time_in_ms] = (params[:my_object][:hour].to_i * 60 * 60 + params[:my_object][:minute].to_i * 60 + params[:my_object][:second].to_i) * 1000
      params.require(:my_object).permit(:name, my_object_times_attributes: [:time_in_ms])
    end
```

However, only the MyObject object is getting saved and not a corresponding MyObjectTime.  Is there a way I can get both to get created at once?  I don’t want a situation where one gets created and the second does not.  I want either both to get created or nothing to happen at all and an error returned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `has_many :my_object_times`, you should use `my_object_times`(***plural***) instead of `my_object_time`(***singular***) in `fields_for` and in `my_object_params` method

```
<%= f.fields_for :my_object_times do |mot| %>
```

And make sure you have ***build*** the ***child*** with the ***parent*** in the `new` method

```
#my_object_controller
def new
  @my_object = MyObject.new
  @my_object.my_object_times.build
end
```

Comment: I already have a line, "<%= f.fields_for :my_object_time do |mot| %>," which I included in my question.  Are you saying pluralize that to "<%= f.fields_for :my_object_times do |mot| %>"?

Comment: @Dave Yes exactly.

Comment: Ok.  The thing is I want the three select_tag fields, where you select hour, minute, and second to ultimately map into my my_object_time.time_in_ms field, which is not happening now.  I included the "my_object_params" method where I try and gather that information into my model, but evidently I'm still not doing something right because the data isn't saved into the db.